# Install Office software on a standard user account automatically

Tags: installation, microsoft-office, administrator, elevation

If I know the Administrator account name and password on a Windows 7 computer, would it be possible to create an Office 2010 install CD that would "silently" install Office 2010 on a standard user account which does not have installation privileges.  As in, the group policy "always install with elevated privileges" is in effect for the user.

Some way to built the admin account privileges into the office installer?

VBS Script?  CMD?

Understand, the laptops are in the field, the end user doesn't have the admin password and can't have the admin password.

Thanks.

Comment: So you're basically asking if you can ship a CD to your road warriors who only have standard user rights that they can use to upgrade office?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was: http://robotronic.de/runasspcEn.html

Answer (score 0):

You can customize office install and do silent deployment with Office Customization Tool. For more information http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179097.aspx Basicly first (the admin) you start the setup with /admin option for Office Customization Tool interface.

for the standart user installation, if the laptops are on domain, you can install with group policy, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602181.aspx

and finally, if you are not on domain, you can try one of these options http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc178988.aspx (actually, group policy option is still requires a domain).

By the way, an important note in technet page, it says that MS is not supporting "Always install with elevated privileges" option for Office 2010 and 2007 setups

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but you couldn't be further off the mark.